# Finding Non Matches in SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT u_s_date, u_s_customer, u_s_product_name, u_f_quantity FROM updated
JOIN accounts ON `name` = u_s_customer
WHERE deleted = 0;
```

That compares of list in a table called `updated` of 400 product orders.  I am joining to a table of `accounts` because not all customer names from the `updated` table are in the `accounts` table.  So that takes the list from 400 to about 300 names.

*What I need is to now make another list of the 100 rows that are **not** being included.*

I tried things like `` JOIN accounts ON `name` <> u_s_customer `` and that obviously didn't work.  I am not good with subqueries and conditions and I am afraid that is the only way to do this.

Can someone give me some help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EXISTS OPERATOR**

```
SELECT *
FROM updated u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM accounts 
                  WHERE `name` = u_s_customer)
```

**LEFT JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM updated LEFT JOIN accounts 
ON `name` = u_s_customer
WHERE name IS NULL
```

**NOT IN**

```
SELECT *
FROM updated 
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT u_s_customer
                   FROM accounts )
```

Comment: I tend to use the LEFT JOIN method most frequently. It tends to perform the best.

Comment: LEFT JOIN was my first option, I should have stated above, but does no work since there are no nulls.  I think the EXISTS will do the job!

Comment: For this kind of query I would use NOT EXISTS Operator.

Comment: When you do a LEFT JOIN `Name` will be NULL for the result set containing rows from second table. Even if your table doesn't have any nulls that result set will have. And when you add the where clause where name is null, it brings back only the non-matching rows from the first table, the 100 rows you are interested in. all three options should return the same result set, performance may differ on bigger tables.

Comment: @M.Ali  Yup, I was wrong.  I just forgot to do `WHERE name IS NULL` on my list.  So it showed the exact same names...